# Утечка памяти в android приложении

Tags: android

Мое приложение состоит из Activity и Service. Сервис делает основную работу (передает данные в фоновом режиме на сервер), Activity используется для управления сервисом.

Первоначально запускается Activity, в нем запускается сервис:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startService(new Intent(this, LocService.class));
}
```

Далее Activity можно закрыть, а сервис оставить работать, либо полностью закрыть приложение (с остановкой сервиса).

Сервис создает в трее Notification. Активити можно повторно открыть через трей или иконку на рабочем столе.

Так вот, при повторном открытии Activity память потребляемая приложением постоянно увеличивается. Может конечно это и нормальный процесс и потом сборщик мусора ее уберет, а может утечка.

Вижу возможные места утечки памяти:

1. При создании сервиса. При каждом создании Activity запускается новый экземпляр сервиса? Но с другой стороны однократный вызов

   stopService(new Intent(this, LocService.class));
   убивает сервис.
2. При запуске активити каждый раз создается новый экземпляр, при этом выделение памяти неизбежно. Остается надеяться на мусорщика, что он все почистит.

PS: Запуск Activity через Notification происходит с флагами

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

иначе создавался второй экземпляр Activity и выход из него по кнопке Back приводил к предыдущему экземпляру Activity. Сейчас все корректно.

Comment: 1. [Investigating Your RAM Usage][1].
 2. [Memory Analysis for Android Applications][2].

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html
  [2]: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: Мусорщик сделал свое дело ))) Приложение было оставлено в фоне с потреблением памяти 100Мб, через 20 минут заглянул в диспетчер задач, оно уже потребляет 5.5Мб.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то могу посоветовать такое:

1) запускай сервис в `onCreate`, а не в `onResume`, потому что если ты свернешь приложение и заново зайдешь, то `onResume` будет вызван заново, в то время как `onCreate` вызывается только один раз. Почитайпро жизненный цикл активити.

2) сделай проверку сервиса что-то вроде такого:

```
             if (сервис не запущеный) {
                 запусти сервис) 
             }
```

погугли [эту](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUA719UA719&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20how%20to%20check%20service%20is%20running) тему, на первой ссылке есть хороший ответ.

3) проверь не дестроишь ли ты случайно сервис при выходе с аппки